# Python Tkinter: How to scroll to home or end of a canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several Tkinter canvases which need to be scrolled using the Home and End keys.

Right now, I have self.upper, self.primary (vertical too), and self.lower. Each of them should be horizontally scrolled. All are stored in a list, so I can scroll all of them with a loop easily.

```
(somecanvas).xview_moveto(0.0)
```

This code scrolls to the beginning. Easy peasy.

```
(somecanvas).xview_moveto(1.0)
```

This code scrolls such the entire canvas is off the left side.

```
(somecanvas).xview_moveto((width - visible) / width)
```

This code scrolls such that it's approximately showing the final pageful of information, but suffers from rounding errors and is overall not precise.

What is the best way to scroll to the end of a canvas?